# Are pixels ever not a square on a monitor?

Tags: windows, user-interface, dpi

I'm working on making my application DPI sensitive using [this MSDN guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464660.aspx) where the technique for scaling uses X and Y logical pixels from a device context.

```
int _dpiX = 96, _pdiY = 96;   
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
if (hdc)
{
    _dpiX = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX);
    _dpiY = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
}
```

Then you can scale X and Y coordinates using

```
int ScaleX(int x) { return MulDiv(x, _dpiX, 96); }
int ScaleY(int y) { return MulDiv(y, _dpiY, 96); }
```

Is there ever a situation where `GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX)` and `GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY)` would return different numbers for a monitor. The only device I'm really concerned about is a monitor so do I need to have separate `ScaleX(int x)` and `ScaleY(int y)` functions? Could I use just one `Scale(int px)` function? Would there be a downside to doing this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is theoretically possible, but I don't know of any recent monitor that uses non-square pixels.  There are so many advantages to square pixels, and so much existing software assumes square pixels, that it seems unlikely for a mainstream monitor to come out with a non-square pixel mode.

In many cases, if you *did* have a monitor with non-square pixels, you probably could apply a transform to make it appear as though it has square pixels (e.g., by setting the mapping mode).

That said, it is common for *printers* to have non-square device units.  Many of them have a much higher resolution in one dimension than in the other.  Some drivers make this resolution available to the caller.  Others will make it appear as though it has square pixels.  If you ever want to re-use your code for printing, I'd advise you to not conflate your horizontal and vertical scaling.

Comment: There are a lot of plasma displays out there (mostly TVs) that have an internal resolution of 1024x768 but are 16:9. Google "plasma 1024x768 16:9" for examples". It's very rare to find this in a computer monitor, but if it's easy to program for, it'd be cool to support that case!

Comment: @Chris:  I suspect that the hardware for a 1024x768 widescreen display is going to apply a transform at a low level.  At the driver level, you'll be presented with the illusion of square pixels, perhaps by using a virtual screen of 1280x720 in a 16x9 arrangement, and the hardware beneath the driver will resample the square virtual pixels to produce the native non-square pixels.  I doubt you'd be able to address the non-square native pixels directly at the WinAPI layer.

Answer (score 4):

Hardware pixels of LCD panels are always square. Using CRT, you can have rectangular square, like using `320x200` or `320x400` resolution on `4:3` monitor (these resolution were actualy used). On LCD you can get rectangular pixels by using non-native resolution on monitor - widescreen resolution on `5:4` monitor and vice versa.